# how get homography matrix from intrinsic and extrinsic parameters to obtain top view image

Tags: homography, perspectivecamera

I'm trying to get top view image from the image captured by a camera in perspective. Already got the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of the camera to the plane , the ground. The camera is positioned on a robot pointed to the ground at a certain height and tilt. For this camera position got:

Intrinsic matrix (3X3):

```
KK= [624.2745,0,327.0749;0,622.0777,232.3448;0,0,1]
```

The translation vector and rotation matrix:

```
T = [-323.708466;-66.960728;1336.693284]

R =[0.0029,1.0000,-0.0034;0.3850,-0.0042,-0.9229;-0.9229,0.0013,-0.3850]
```

How can I get a Homography matrix to get top view image of the ground (chess set in the ground), with the information I have?

I'm using matlab. I've done the code to apply the matrix H to the captured image, but I still haven´t i way the get this H matrix properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @hiro potagonist even I am having the same problem. I am doing it in opencv. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji i only edited the question; but it's not mine, sorry! you'd have to ask David Fernandes.

Comment: @David Fernandes Did you figure out how to do it?